# Comparing values inside a 2D Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a question where I need to compare the values inside a 2D Array in java. For example:

```
int N = 2, c = 2;
int [][] arr = new int[N][c];

System.out.println("Enter the values to a 2D array: ");

for(int i=0; i<N;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<c;j++) {
        arr[i][j]=in.nextInt();
    }     
}
```

So in the above code, the user enters the values inside a 2d array. 
Now I want to compare if `arr[i]>=0` and `arr[j]>=0` separately and if yes, I need to perform some other operation on this.

But I'm not able to do it that way. Example:

```
for(int i=0; i<N;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<c;j++) {
        if (arr[i]>=0 && arr[j]>=0) {
            //Some operation//
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly suggest me a way to do this operation - comparing the values individually. Thank you.

Comment: it is not clear what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

`arr1[i]` is an array of integers, not an integer, so you can't compare it to an integer. `arr1[i][j]` is an `int`, and can be compared to integers.

`if (arr[i][j]>=0)` is a valid syntax, but it's not clear if that's what you want.

Comment: how do it individually compare there values .. is there any way ?

Comment: @Dev Compare what? An array of integers to 0? What's the meaning of such a comparison? Do you wish to compare each number in the array to 0?

Answer (score 1):

To compare value of a two dimensional array you should go through with each value of that array.

> 2x2 array
>
> . .
>
> . .
>
> when i=0, j=0
>
> x .
>
> . .
>
> when i=0, j=1
>
> . x
>
> . .
>
> when i=1, j=0
>
> . .
>
> x .
>
> when i=1, j=1
>
> . .
>
> . x

```
   for(int i=0; i<N;i++) {
      for (int j=0;j<c;j++) {
         if (arr[i][j]>=your_comparable_value ) {
             //Some operation//
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing integers in a 2D array. If it helps, you can visually model 2D arrays by thinking of rows and columns - each row and column pair references it's respective storage location in the array. Example:

```
arr[0][1] = 5; // sets the value of row [0] column [1] to 5
```

In the second nested 'for' loop (the one you are having some trouble with), you incorrectly referencing the values of your 2D array. Remember, you must specify the pair - arr[int][int] - in which you wish to reference.

```
if (arr[i]>=0 && arr[j]>=0); //  incorrect way of referencing the desired respective location in the 2D array
```

Your revised nested 'for' loop with the syntactically accurate 'if' statement:

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<c; j++) // side note: consider using final constant(s) replacing variables N and c. In your case, you are explicitly referencing two integers that store the same value - 2
        if (arr[i][j]>=0)
            System.out.println("Array Position [" + i + "][" + j + "] is greater than or equal to 0");
```

Comment: `arr` does not expect two integers. `arr[i]` is a valid array of integers, but can't be compared with 0.

Comment: thanks for the help.  Understood the logic behind it.